# How to Update ObservableCollection on click in c# with or without using LINQ in Windows 10 universal app development

Tags: c#, windows, linq, xaml, observablecollection

Hello I am new to Windows app development and I am trying to update a ObservableCollection in c# To reflect the changes dynamically in xaml UI .But the changes does not reflect in UI.Am i doing anything wrong or it doesn't work for Windows 10 or what.

Someone please correct me or suggest me a another best approach than what i am doing.

Thanks in Advance.

My Class:

```
public class Students
{
      public string Name;
      public int Age;
      Public int Section_no; 
 }
```

My C# code:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Students> student = new ObservableCollection<Students>();




    private void FilterItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuFlyoutItem selectedItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;

        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            if (selectedItem.Tag.ToString() == "section")
            {
                student =new ObservableCollection<Students>(student.OrderBy(i => i.Section_no));
             }
            else if (selectedItem.Tag.ToString() == "age")
            {
                student = new ObservableCollection<Students>(student.OrderBy(i => i.Age));
            }
            else if (selectedItem.Tag.ToString() == "name")
            {
                student = new ObservableCollection<Students>(student.OrderBy(i => i.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `student` variable must be a **Property** in order for your UI to bind to it correctly. Not only that, it must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, as you are creating new instances of the collection in your method.

```
private ObservableCollection<Student> _Students;

public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
{
    get { return _Students; }
    set
    {
        _Students = value;

        //Notify property changed stuff.
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your containing class.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to dynamically update your UI, you need to use Data Binding.  First your object class, each property will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  When done correctly, any change to those properties will be automatically propogated to the UI.  Then assuming your ObservableCollection is set as the ItemsSource of the ListView, any changes to it will be propogated as well.

Here is a quick article on implementing Data Binding with INotifyPropertyChanged.  It is written for Windows 8.1 Universal Apps, but will work the same with Windows 10.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quick_thoughts/archive/2014/06/10/data-binding-part-3-implementing-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface.aspx